# Different ways how to switch channel between read and write modes - when to use which?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

Reading various manuals on programming Java NIO socket two different was are used to switch channel/selector mode (expected next operation) between `SelectionKey.OP_READ` and  `SelectionKey.OP_WRITE`, in order to read or write into the channel. One way is using `SelectionKey.interestOps()` call, the other to use `socketChannel.register()`.

```
SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)keyIterator.next();
...
SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
...
socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
// or ?  
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

The `SelectionKey` and `SocketChannel` are clearly bound together, at least in one key loop iteration. `Selector` is linked to both indirectly. Just saying.

There code source for `sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps()` is NOT provided with JDK. The source code for `java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register()` is provided, and yes, internally it indeed calls `SelectionKey.interestOps()` but also `SelectionKey.attach()`, the *key* is there is obtained by a lookup which I see unnecessary as we already have it; and couple of checks. So, both calls do same job under the hood, just that *register* does a bit more.

My question is: which one to use and when?

**2019-09-04 update:**
According to the [The Rox Java NIO Tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/), frequently cited on SO, thou quite dated, it's from times before Java 5; what they do is what was suggestested in the comments here:

- `socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ)` is done only once, on initial `accept()`.
- subsequently they use only
  `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE)` and `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`

I also posted a related question: [Is it necessary to register interest to write to a NIO socket to send data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779357/is-it-necessary-to-register-interest-to-write-to-a-nio-socket-to-send-data) investigating when, and if, it is actually necessary to register interest for `OP_WRITE`.

Comment: There is no such thing in NIO as 'read mode' or 'write mode' or 'next expected operation', and therefore no such thing as switching between them either. You've been reading nonsense. You are registering for *events* that you are *interested* in if they happen. You have to use `register()` the first time: after that you should use `interestOps()` to conserve the registration key.

Comment: Sure, they are colloquial terms. I am happy to be advised how to address them properly.

Comment: Have a look aound here for my comments on the Rox tutorial. They are far from flattering. There are many questions here about how to use OP_WRITE correctly, and some of them even have correct answers ;-) Anybody telling you that you can't write without a prior OP_WRITE doesn't know what he is talking about, by definition.