# Is it necessary to register interest to write to a NIO socket to send data?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

Is it necessary to register interest to write to a NIO client socket channel to send data? Do I have to always call `socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE)`, or some equivalent, before writing to the client `SocketChannel` to be able to write there?

Would not be enough simply to write data to client `SocketChannel` with `channel.write(outputBuffer)` and awake potentially blocked `Selector`, all in a client thread? The main selector loop would then look like this:

```
Selector selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

while (selector.select() > 0) {  
    Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = readyKeys.iterator();

    while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)keyIterator.next();
        keyIterator.remove();
        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
           ...
           if (key.isAcceptable()) {
               ...
               SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
               socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
               socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
               // client socket channel would be permanently in the read mode
               ...
           } else if (key.isReadable()) {
               ...
           } else if (key.isWritable()) { 
               // the key should know here that the underlying channel
               // has something to be send to the wire, so it should get 
               // here if there are still data to be sent
               socketChannel.write(outputBuffer)
           }
```

It would only get to the `if (key.isWritable())` branch when there is something remaining to be send, the remainder of data from the initial `channel.write(outputBuffer)` call; like when the message is too long and needs to be send out into chunks and I want no blocking. The loop would spin until `outputBuffer.hasRemaining()` is finally `false`.

I am even thinking, does have to be writing to Channel, that is sending data out, done through Selector at all? Leave only incoming traffic to be handled with Selector, as only incoming traffic need *wait* states?

**UPDATE**

From further reading of valuable *user207421* posts, which I partly inspired me to post this question, NIO Javadoc, in the push to join the dots, I summarized this:

- SocketChannel and SelectionKey are thread safe.
- Reading and writing from/to channel socket outside the selector loop is indeed possible; it's independent of it. Reading outside does not make much sense, writing to socket definitively does and it's in fact how most of writing is done.
- Writing of data is typically initiated outside the selector loop, in a different thread. `write(buffer)` will not necessary send all data - if the message is too huge for the socket buffer, remote client is very slow or even went unresponsive. In that case `write()` has to be called repeatedly. Buffer updates the current position with every call, depending how much was sent, which can be anything between `0` and `buffer.remaining()`.
- If `write()` returns `0` then, and *user207421* cannot stress this more, it's the case, possibly the only one, when `OP_WRITE` needs to be registered and writing is then handled within selector loop.
- When all data are written the `OP_READ` must be immediately restored
- Having `OP_WRITE` set without any data to write would cause selector loop to endlessly spin; waste of CPU time.
- It is unclear what to do if `write()` returns `>0` but still not all remaining message data were sent, that is `buffer.remaining() > 0`. Should I also set `OP_WRITE` and pass it to selector loop, or loop `write(buffer)` inside writing thread until there is no remainder or `0` is returned?
- Can actually such situation happen? Official `SocketChannel` Javadoc says initially *Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after writing all of the r requested bytes* ..meaning, no, it cannot happen! But then they add:  *Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes* ..so does it mean `write()` can return before sending all? Or does that mean that returns '0' if it sent, say, just half of the buffer?
- In the *write returned 0* scenario, when writing is passed to the selector loop, ie different thread; is the writing thread blocked to write a completely new message, ie new buffer, to the same socket channel? Or I have to ensure it does not happen by other means? The Javadoc says: *This method may be invoked at any time. If another thread has already initiated a write operation upon this channel, however, then an invocation of this method will block until the first operation is complete.* Does that cover my scenario?
- Official Javadoc does not mention any special meaning for `0` as a return value for `write()` method. It just says: *The number of bytes written, possibly zero*. Hmm.
- I'm also not sure how unresponsive or slow client is handled during the write. I'm guessing that returning `0` from `write()` and passing it to selector loop is exactly the reason it's done like that. Selector then can, and I'm only guessing here, manage writing in an optimal way: speeding it, slowing it, increasing intervals, sending smaller chunks, whatever; whatever the underlying TCP/IP stack reports back.

Comment: No. Just write. A socket is normally writeable, unless he received is slow reading and his receive window has backed up and closed. If you get a short or zero-length write, *then* is the time to register for OP_WRITE and await writability. As soon as you can write, unregistered it.

Comment: And you don't need to 'awake potentially blocked `Selector` either.

Comment: @user207421 Helpful, thanks! Why not make it a full answer. I'm happy to rate it. Ideally, if you clarify a bit more on "If you get a short write". Short in a sense that not all bytes from the buffer were written to the channel? How to detect it? Just by comparing return value from `channel.write()`? accumulated if necessary or `buffer.remaining()` against known message length?

Comment: Yes, short in that fewer bytes were written than you requested. You detect it via the return code of `write()` and so forth. I've answered enough questions here on this that I don't need to add any more answers.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry to disagree, I actually posted this question exactly *because* of you answers. Sorry, I did not realized it's you; you know, user207421, is not the snappiest name to instantly recognize. You are throwing good bones, no doubts about it; you are probably the only one active around here who clearly understands the matter, but I am still missing more consistent explanation of why the NIO API is as it is. There is a total absence of good reading materials and reliable code samples with in depth explanations; until this is not addressed people will ask stupid questions.

Comment: Well this is one of the reasons I have stopped answering questions here. Despite having covered this all extensively many times in the past, I am once again being expected to say it all again and now to health-check about a dozen assertions. You've broadened your question so far it would require a dissertation to answer it, or a book. I've written one. E.J. Pitt, *Fundamental Networking in Java,* Springer 2005. Recommended reading.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for the reading tip, I'll look it up.